# mobicent container not able to initialize sip servlet

Tags: servlets, sip, mobicents-sip-servlets

Hi I am new to sip servlets.

I put sip.xml & web.xml in WEB-INF directory.

I am using mobicents tomcat server to deploy the application.  When I start the server I am expecting the loggers i written in init() method should be printed on console.  But, somehow container is not able to initialize the sip servlet.

I am trying to interact with the sip servlet using sip phone & x-lite but, connection failed.

am i doing anything wrong.

I deleted sip.xml file from project, I didn't get any error or warning.   I think container is not able to read the sip.xml file.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to help without seeing logs files, please post your questions to groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobicents-public with code sample and logs files of such a test call.